# Run program at startup, detached and as another user?

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, windows-service, windows-10

I need to run dnscrypt-proxy:
1. run automatically at startup or at my logon
2. windowless (not attached to cmd.exe)
3. as another user (not as my username)

If I use cmd.exe's `runas`, then dnscrypt-proxy.exe will also close when I close cmd.exe. It will not detach from cmd.exe:

```
runas /savecred /user:anotheruser "path-to\dnscrypt-proxy.exe"
```

Running dnscrypt-proxy.exe as a service will run it detached but how can I make it also run as another user?

I would like to use whatever programs that already come with Windows 10 Home rather than relying on third party software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `cmd.exe`'s `start` and `runas` to no avail.
I tried using `services.msc` and `taskschd.msc` to no avail.

The only thing that worked was this PowerShell script. Place these lines into a `.ps1` file in `C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\filename.ps1` and will work as intended. (Probably `C#` would work too but I did not research it.)

```
$username = "otherusername"
$password = "password"

$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList @($username,(ConvertTo-SecureString -String $password -AsPlainText -Force))

Set-Location "C:\Program Files\dnscrypt-proxy-win64"
Start-Process -FilePath ".\dnscrypt-proxy.exe" -Credential ($credentials) -ArgumentList "--resolver-name=dnscrypt.eu-dk
 --resolvers-list=dnscrypt-resolvers.csv" -WindowStyle Hidden

Start-Sleep -Seconds 5

if (Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.path -eq "C:\Program Files\dnscrypt-proxy-win64\dnscrypt-proxy.exe"})
{
    # program is running
} else {
    # program is NOT running
    New-Item -ItemType file -Path C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\dnscrypt-proxy-failed-to-start.txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `start` command to run the runas command detached.

`C:\start runas /savecred /user:anotheruser "path-to\dnscrypt-proxy.exe"`

(here you can find some more information on the start command http://www.robvanderwoude.com/ntstart.php)

Comment: dnscrypt-proxy.exe is still executed attached to cmd.exe. When cmd.exe is closed, it closes too. Using `start ""` also is attached.

Comment: Maybe this can help? [link](http://superuser.com/questions/198525/how-can-i-execute-a-windows-command-line-in-background)